# To Show that a group is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to understand the following problem[image]

When I looked at the question, I felt if $a\in G$, then for every positive integer m, $a^m \in G$. Isn't this true? because a Group should satisfy the closure property?

And then it is given in the question as $a^m b^m = b^m a^m$. Which means that the group is abelian. Where am I going wrong with this argument?

If I am wrong in taking $a^m \in G$, then in the solution given in the book, at many places he used things like assuming $c = (b^n a^m)^x$ and then using $a^m c^m = c^m a^m$.

But according to the question this can be used only when a and c are elements of G. How did the author here decide that c belongs to G?

Comment: This is true that $a^m\in G$. But how do you go from $a^nb^m=b^ma^m$ to $G$ being abelian, i.e. the statement that $ab=ba$ for all $a,b\in G$?

Comment: $a^m b^m=b^ma^m$ for all $a$, $b\in G$ does not entail $G$ is Abelian. Consider a non-Abelian group of order $m$..

Comment: Thanks a lot guys... I figured it out.